# Calculation based on variable Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a report i was asked to create, I have completed the main part of it but some of the calculations are getting me.

[image]

This is the template that I was provided, i have recreated it but the Close Rate, Prior, and Change are getting me. I cannot figure out how to calculate them, the close rate is the Closed amount divided by the Grand Total.

[image]

[image]

The Status column is populated by

```
=Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value)
```

The Grand Total is populated by

```
=Sum(Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value))
```

I have tried

```
=IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "CLOSED", (Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value))/ (Sum(Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value))), 0)
```

but that does not work as it returns a 1, any ideas what to try next?

Is there a way of saying either divide the number in the CLOSED column by the Grand Total or divide count of CallDateYear by the total only on the rows with CLOSED as a status.

Comment: Am not pretty clear by the `Fields!Status.Value = "CLOSED"` thing you are doing but to get the **Close Rate** all you need to do is             
 `(Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value))/ (Sum(Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value)` **OR** `((Fields!ClosedAmount.Value/Fields!GrandTotal.Value)*100)` 

and to bring the **%** put a `Number Format` as `0.00,'%'#`

Comment: For the Close Rate percentage I only need to divide the rows that are "CLOSED" by the grand total, when i  apply       `(Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value))/ (Sum(Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value)`  the count of CallDateYear is equal to the sum count as it is not being filtered by the status. I almost need to do a `Count(Fields!CallDateYear.Value) WHERE [Status] = "CLOSED"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, i Created another column group grouped by [Status] and set the visibility of the Column group to hide columns with "Open" as their status, i then set the expression for the average to compare to the text box value for the Grand total,

```
=(Count(Fields!CallDateMonth.Value))/ReportItems("Textbox234").Value
```

[image]